# Reading the contents of ZIP file in silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, file, download, zip

i am making an application in Silverlight. In that application i am downloading a ZIP file. That ZIP file contain a strings.Here i want read the string from ZIP file one by one for further processing. I am using code as

```
client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted+=new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Here logic for reading the contents of zip file
}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) that supports Silverlight to extract files from a zip archive.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But can you tell me how to use that SharpZipLib in application?

Comment: @Dany first of all, SharpZipLib and DotNetZip are different things. Then, SO is not a forum but a question/answer site. Gimme-da-codez questions are not welcome here. There exist examples of use for given libraries, which you can use.

Comment: @Dany, the landing page of the DotNetZip library that I have linked to contains an example of how to achieve that. Did you read it? Did you try something? Did you encounter some particular problems with your code?